# How to add sr-only class to input's label?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

I have simple form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @link do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :url, placeholder: "http://..." %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Submit Link", class: "btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

it outputs input like this:

```
<div class="form-group url required link_url">
  <label class="url required control-label" for="link_url">
    <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Url
  </label>
  <input class="string url required form-control" placeholder="http://..." type="url" name="link[url]" id="link_url">
</div>
```

How can I add 'sr-only' class to label element?

Comment: try something like this `<%= f.input :url, placeholder: "http://...", input_html: { :class => "sr-only" }%>`

Comment: it adds `sr-only` to input element, not the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
<%= f.input :url, placeholder: "http://...", label_html: { class: 'sr-only' } %>
```